# Value of complex angle in Snell's law

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics, complex-numbers

According to Snell's law:

$$\sin \theta_t = \displaystyle \frac{n_1}{n_2} \sin \theta_i$$

where $\theta_i$ is the incidence angle in medium 1 and (after the ray crossed the interface between medium 1 and 2) $\theta_t$ is the resulting angle in medium 2.

If $n_1 > n_2$, there will be a critical incidence angle $\theta_c$ (such that $\sin \theta_c = n_2 / n_1$), which causes $\sin \theta_t = 1$. When $\theta_i > \theta_c$, $\sin \theta_t$ is forced to be a value greater than $1$, which is not achievable through a real value of $\theta_t$.

Even though this angle $\theta_t$ has no physical meaning, which is its exact mathematical value? And is it unique?

---

**My attempt:**

Near the end of [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/313368/42377), the value $\theta = \pi / 2 + n \pi + iI$ ($I \neq 0$) is suggested to generate a value $\sin \theta > 1$. But it seems not to be the case: in fact,

\begin{align}
\sin \theta 
& = \frac{e^{i \theta} - e^{- i \theta}}{2i} 
= \frac{e^{i \left( \frac{\pi}{2} + n \pi + iI \right)} - e^{- i \left( \frac{\pi}{2} + n \pi + iI \right)}}{2i} 
\\ & = \frac{i \cos(n \pi) e^{-I} + i \cos(n \pi) e^I}{2i} 
= \cos (n \pi) \cosh I 
\\ & = (-1)^n \cosh I 
\end{align}

It seems not correct. The value $\theta = \pi / 2 - iI$ seems more appropriate. In fact:

\begin{align}
\sin \theta 
& = \frac{e^{i \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - iI \right)} - e^{- i \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - iI \right)}}{2i} 
 & = \frac{i e^I + i e^{-I}}{2i} 
\\& = \cosh I 
\end{align}

and

$$\cosh I \geq 1, \forall I \in \mathbb{R}$$

So,

$$\cosh I = \frac{n_1}{n_2} \sin \theta_i, \ I = \mathrm{arccosh} \mathopen{} \left( \frac{n_1}{n_2} \sin \theta_i \right)$$

So, the initial question becomes: is this procedure correct?

Comment: related subject posted for no good reason: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/131478/955

Comment: The meaning of a pure imaginary number $\;\cos\theta_t\;$ is given by Jackson : [7.4 Polarization by Reflection and Total Internal Reflection](https://imgur.com/a/1rPxVbp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, complex angles just aren't worth the hassle. As the answer you've linked to points out, they're just a complicated way to re-parametrize the evanescent wave
$$
e^{i\mathbf k\cdot \mathbf r}
= e^{i(k_x,0,i\kappa)\cdot (x,y,z)}
=e^{ik_x x}e^{-\kappa z}
\ \ \stackrel{\rm as}{=} \ \ 
e^{ik(\sin(\theta),0,\cos(\theta))\cdot\mathbf r}
.
$$

For the total-internal-reflection case that you ask about, take the form above for the evanescent wave in medium $2$ for $z>0$, so that you're required to have
$$
k_x^2 -\kappa^2 = k_2^2 = \frac{n_2^2}{n_1^2} k_1^2.
$$
With that notation in place, *any* angle that fulfills the equations
\begin{align}
k_2 \sin(\theta) & = k_{x,1} \\
k_2 \cos(\theta) & = i\kappa,
\end{align}
or equivalently
\begin{align}
\sin(\theta) & = \frac{n_1}{n_2}\sin(\theta_i) \\
\cos(\theta) & = i\sqrt{ \frac{n_1^2}{n_2^2}\sin^2(\theta_i)-1 }
,
\end{align}
is an acceptable solution $-$ so long as those two conditions are satisfied, even if you get different $\theta$s, the consequences for the real-world waveforms are exactly identical, and the $\theta$s cannot be differentiated on the basis of any physical observable. On the other hand, it's important to note that *both* of these conditions need to be satisfied, or you run the risk of having an incorrect sign for $\kappa$ and, with that, an exponentially-increasing wave where you were meant to have a quickly-decaying evanescent wave.

To fully characterize the complex angle, let's work our conditions some more, though, by expanding out the angle into its real and imaginary parts, $\theta = \theta_\mathrm{re}+i \theta_\mathrm{im}$ (with $\theta_\mathrm{re},\theta_\mathrm{im} \in \mathbb R$),
\begin{align}
\sin(\theta_\mathrm{re})\cosh(\theta_\mathrm{im}) + i\cos(\theta_\mathrm{re})\sinh(\theta_\mathrm{im}) 
& = \frac{n_1}{n_2}\sin(\theta_i) \\
\cos(\theta_\mathrm{re})\cosh(\theta_\mathrm{im}) - i\sin(\theta_\mathrm{re})\sinh(\theta_\mathrm{im})
 & = i\sqrt{ \frac{n_1^2}{n_2^2}\sin^2(\theta_i)-1 }
,
\end{align}
and then requiring that the real and imaginary parts of these equations be satisfied simultaneously,
\begin{align}
\sin(\theta_\mathrm{re})\cosh(\theta_\mathrm{im}) & = \frac{n_1}{n_2}\sin(\theta_i) \\
\cos(\theta_\mathrm{re})\sinh(\theta_\mathrm{im}) & = 0 \\
\cos(\theta_\mathrm{re})\cosh(\theta_\mathrm{im}) & = 0 \\
\sin(\theta_\mathrm{re})\sinh(\theta_\mathrm{im}) & = - \sqrt{ \frac{n_1^2}{n_2^2}\sin^2(\theta_i)-1 }
.
\end{align}
Since $\theta_\mathrm{im}$ is real, which guarantees that $\cosh(\theta_\mathrm{im})>0$, we conclude from $\cos(\theta_\mathrm{re})\cosh(\theta_\mathrm{im}) = 0$ that
$$
\cos(\theta_\mathrm{re}) = 0
$$
and therefore that
$$
\theta_\mathrm{re} = \frac{\pi}{2} + n \pi, \ \ n\in \mathbb Z,
$$
as a necessary condition, which then implies that $\sin(\theta_\mathrm{re}) = (-1)^n$, so we still need to solve both of
\begin{align}
\cosh(\theta_\mathrm{im}) & = (-1)^n\frac{n_1}{n_2}\sin(\theta_i) \\
\sinh(\theta_\mathrm{im}) & = - (-1)^n\sqrt{ \frac{n_1^2}{n_2^2}\sin^2(\theta_i)-1 }
.
\end{align}
Here the second equation is always solvable, as
$$
\theta_\mathrm{im} = - (-1)^n\mathrm{arcsinh} \mathopen{}\left(\sqrt{ \frac{n_1^2}{n_2^2}\sin^2(\theta_i)-1 }\right),
$$
and this will guarantee the correct sign for $\kappa$, but the first equation is only possible if $(-1)^n\sin(\theta_i)>0$, where you can conclude that $n$ is even **if** the incidence angle is counted as positive. This is a reasonable convention, but it is *not* guaranteed, and a more general solution is to adjust the offset $n$ according to the sign of the incidence angle as
$$
(-1)^n = \mathrm{sgn}(\theta_i),
$$
giving $\theta_\mathrm{re} = \frac{\pi}{2} \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 2\pi)$ for $\theta_i> 0$, and choosing $n=-1$ as the principal representative for the opposite case, $\theta_\mathrm{re} = -\frac{\pi}{2} \ (\mathrm{mod}\  2\pi)$ for $\theta_i< 0$. This means, then, that the correct solution is
\begin{align}
\theta_\mathrm{re} & = \mathrm{sgn}(\theta_i) \frac{\pi}{2}
\\
\theta_\mathrm{im} & = - \mathrm{sgn}(\theta_i) \mathrm{arcsinh} \mathopen{}\left(\sqrt{ \frac{n_1^2}{n_2^2}\sin^2(\theta_i)-1 }\right),
\end{align}
or in other words
$$
\theta = \mathrm{sgn}(\theta_i) \left[
\frac{\pi}{2} - i\: \mathrm{arcsinh} \mathopen{}\left(\sqrt{ \frac{n_1^2}{n_2^2}\sin^2(\theta_i)-1 }\right)\right]  \mod 2\pi
$$
as the general solution.

I've phrased things like this because they're a surefire way to guarantee the correct signs, but it's clunkier than it needs to be, so it can be simplified a bit to swap that arcsinh-of-a-square-root for a simpler arccosh: to do that, start by writing
\begin{align}
\cosh(\theta_\mathrm{im}) & = (-1)^n\frac{n_1}{n_2}\sin(\theta_i)  = \frac{n_1}{n_2}\left|\sin(\theta_i)\right|
\end{align}
(since the $(-1)^n$ factor is there to guarantee positivity), allowing you to write
\begin{align}
\theta_\mathrm{im} = \pm \mathrm{arccosh} \mathopen{}\left(\frac{n_1}{n_2}\left|\sin(\theta_i)\right|\right)
\end{align}
up to a sign ambiguity which we've resolved above. With the sign resolution from above, though, we get as our final result
$$
\theta = \mathrm{sgn}(\theta_i) \left[
\frac{\pi}{2} - i\: \mathrm{arccosh} \mathopen{}\left(\frac{n_1}{n_2}\left|\sin(\theta_i)\right|\right)\right]  \mod 2\pi
.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer, which I am trying to follow and understand. A doubt: "Since $\theta_i$ is given and real, which guarantees that $\cosh(\theta_i) > 0$, we conclude that $\cos(\theta_{\mathrm{re}})=0$". I agree with the first part: a real $\theta_i$ generates $\cosh(\theta_i) > 0$, and even $\cosh \theta_i \geq 1$. But what is the relation with the second part? In the four equations preceding this statement there is no $\cosh \theta_i$. There are only $\cosh \theta_{\mathrm{im}}$ and $\sinh \theta_{\mathrm{im}}$.

Comment: Also, "as a necessary condition, which then implies that $\sin(\theta_r) = (−1)^n$": maybe you were meaning $\sin(\theta_{\mathrm{re}}) = (−1)^n$.

Comment: Ah, those are remnants of a previous draft with inconsistent notation, which I obviously didn't get rid of fully. Still, the conclusions are unaffected.

Comment: I imagined this. Thanks! But I still can't solve the doubt in the first comment...

Comment: @BowPark See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you not only for the edit, but also for all the considerations in the post and the very thorough explanation about the sign. A (hopefully, last) doubt. The last expression of $\theta$ is perfectly coherent with the previous one containing $\mathrm{arcsinh}$. But, from what you wrote, in the case of positive $\theta_i$, it is 

$$\theta_{\mathrm{im}} = \mathrm{arccosh} \left[ \frac{n_1}{n_2} \sin (\theta_i) \right]$$

so in the final expression for $\theta$ (last line) there should be a $+$ sign between $\pi / 2$ and the $\mathrm{arccosh}$. Why isn't so? What am I missing?

Comment: All I can say is that, being $$\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} + \alpha \right) = \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha \right)$$ the $\theta$ in the last line will generate the same result as before in the case of $\theta_i > 0$. In the case of $\theta_i < 0$, it would be

$$\theta = - \left[ \frac{\pi}{2} + i\: \mathrm{arccosh} \mathopen{}\left(\frac{n_1}{n_2}\left|\sin(\theta_i)\right|\right)\right]  \mod 2\pi$$

But being the sine an odd function, the resulting $\sin (\theta)$ would still be equal to $-\sin (\theta)$, as it happens using the above expressions of $\theta$ with $\mathrm{arcsin}$.

Comment: Your first equation looks wrong to me. The rigorous sign handling shows that if $\theta_i>0$ then $\theta_\mathrm{im}$ should be negative.

Comment: Either way, though, that just serves to further underline the point: **complex angles just aren't worth the hassle.** Even if you do get the signs correct, what have you actually learned, and how is the resulting formalism any better than just using complex wavevectors? (hint: not much, and not at all, resp.) If you do want to continue digging, hopefully the existing material in this answer will be sufficient to answer your questions, but I'm bowing out of further back-and-forth on this one.

Comment: Ok, got it and got your hints. I can only add thank you.